# Where are the capabilities of the iccube's web user interface for creating a report described?

Tags: iccube-reporting

When one points his browser to http://localhost:8282/icCube/doc/ic3report, he is taken to a web user interface for creating a report. I looked through iccube documentation (which is admittedly very extensive), but could not find a description of this web user interface and its capabilities. If someone was able to find it, I will very much appreciate a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface the reporting is using to communicate with the server uses an internal protocol, we call it GVI (HTTP/JSON). It's not public and we don't guarantee it won't change. It's javascript so easy to trace but at your own risk.

The public documentation we've is for integrating icCube reports [here](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/reporting/doc/ic3WebAppIntegration.php) and one for the reporting widget should follow.

Comment: I am not asking about integration, but rather about composing a report by using the wizard.

Comment: No really , we've worked a lot on it so doing a documentation was put on hold till is stable enough (it's now). It should be autoexplanatory Will come on the meantime you can check a few videos, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJ8ofbYSbQE but I guess you are looking for this https://www.iccube.com/livedemo (still not migrated to the latest reporting)

Comment: This is the real answer to my question. Thanks!